# Why doesn't my NSOperationQueue stop executing when suspended?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsoperationqueue

I have a loop which I run and in each **iteration** I have a block that I want run on an `NSOperationQueue`.  The underlying queue is serial.  This loop could add hundreds of potentially long running block tasks.  When I set `m_opQueue.suspended = YES` the blocks will still keep executing.

I'm well aware that a single block cannot stop right in the middle, but I expected that pausing the `NSOperationQueue` would simply not execute the next operation until suspended was false.

Can anyone explain whether I'm wrong or how I achieve what I want?

```
dispatch_queue_t index_queue = dispatch_queue_create("someQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
m_OpQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
m_OpQueue.underlyingQueue = index_queue;


for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < total; i++ ) {

    void (^block)(void) = ^void() {            
        // Do stuff.
        NSLog(@"processing complete.");

    };

    // Effectively adds a NSBlockOperation.
    [m_OpQueue addOperationWithBlock:block];

}
```

Comment: no you are right - normally a queue will not start new operations if suspended.. show how  you make the queue.. maybe it is a concurrent queue with more than one block in parallel?

Comment: Details on how I create the queue are updated.  I wonder if this has something to do with the fact that it's using NSBlockOperation.  The doc says, "Blocks added to a block operation are dispatched with default priority to an appropriate work queue. The blocks themselves should not make any assumptions about the configuration of their execution environment."  But it would seem correct that these blocks are executed on the underlying queue I set on NSOperationQueue.

Comment: Please show the code where you suspend the queue.

Comment: No. The operations are on the underlying Queue. The Blocks dont have to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This curious behavior you describe (where previously enqueued operations will continue to start even after the queue has been suspended), is caused by how you created the serial queue.

Generally, you create a serial operation queue by setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount`:

```
m_OpQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

If you do that (no need to set `underlyingQueue`), you see the expected behavior.

Comment: Ahh, such a silly oversight.  Then again Apple docs tend leave a lot to the imagination.  Thanks for your answer.  An interesting side note though, you mention that there's no need to set the underlying queue if setting the maxConcurrentOperationCount equal to1.  While you're absolutely correct, I notice that if I don't set it the blocks run on different threads (still serial) similar to how GCD normally behaves.  If I keep the underlying queue, it will always execute those blocks on the same thread, which is more desirable in my case.

Comment: Agreed. Admittedly, 99% of the time, one doesn't care what thread it runs on (as long as the desired queue behavior is honored, e.g. in this case, that the operations are serial with respect to each other), but for those rare cases where you need to specify what thread it's on (e.g. "to have enqueued operations interspersed with blocks submitted to that dispatch queue"), you can use `underlyingQueue`.

Comment: The whole point about NSOperationQueue is NOT using dispatch_queue APIs... not even setting the underlying queue...